# Restrict operations in restful PHP API

Tags: php, angularjs

I am creating an AngularJS application with a restful API written in PHP as backend. This is the first time I'm using AngularJS and PHP "together".

Angular is keeping track of the authentication of users using the ngCookies module. Some operations, like deleting stuff, should only be available for users with specific privileges. How can I make sure that "normal" users or users that have not logged in cannot access the deletion operations of the API?

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I do it.

1. In `users` DB table I add column named `token VARCHAR(36)`
2. Whenever user logs in:
3. I update `lastlogin` column
4. I update that token with `MD5($ip.$email.$logindate)`
5. Now I return user object to Angular and angular knows token.
6. In Angular `$http` service I add interceptors and before any request is made `Authentication` header is set. I use basic authentication. I create string `$user_id.'::'.$token`.

   ```
   app.factory('authInterceptor', function($rootScope, $q, appConfig, $injector, $cacheFactory) {
       function request(config) {
           if(angular.isDefined($rootScope.currentUser.id)) {
               config.headers.Authorization = 'Basic ' +
               window.btoa($rootScope.currentUser.id + ':' +
               $rootScope.currentUser.token);
           }

           return config;
       }

       function response(response) {
           if(angular.isDefined(response.data.code) && parseInt(response.data.code) == 401) {
               var UserApi = $injector.get('UserApi');

               UserApi.logout();

               $cacheFactory.get('$http').removeAll();

               UserApi.login(response.data.message)
                   .catch(function() {
                       var $state = $injector.get('$state');
                       $state.go('app.home');
                   });
           }

           return response || $q.when(response);
       }

       return {
           request:  request,
           response: response
       };
   })
   ```

This is my `authInterceptor` factory that I insert into app

```
app.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
})
```

What is happening there I set standard `Authentication` header for every request if user is authorised.

Then in PHP I get this header. I get user ID and Token separately. Then I use user ID to get user data from DB where I have token and last login date.

Now I can compare token and see if this user is the one who logged in.

But this is not absolutely secure. If anyone get this token, then he can login. That is why IP is used. not only I check the token against one in DB I also check it against IP. I create `MD5($ip.$email.$logindate)` because I know all that data and check against token that I get from angular. If it was sent from different IP it will not pass through.

You can also see function response in `authInterceptor`. Whenever I have authentication problem I send back HTTP code `401`. Now in response I know that Authentication failed. I logout user and redirect him to homepage of the site.

Now it is very simple to code. You just return what have to be returned, and do not care about none authenticated user.

But there is more. If you need some kind of ACL, then you can design this as you wish. In your class that return particular RESTFull API method you can define `$acl` property and set name of the group. In the same place where you check for authentication, you can check for ACL too.

Please see my code here it is PHP backend and Angular frontend

https://github.com/Coach-Hub

This is the basic Idea, you can of course build around that.

Comment: This was the inspiration I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

I am not a php developer. You can not ensure this thing in front-end-side. Below is the sample code we use in NodeJs app, to validate user has valid permission of deletion or not.

```
router.patch('/:id', auth.hasRole(userEnums.roles.admin), controller.update);
router.post('/create', auth.hasRole(userEnums.roles.admin), controller.create);
//Checks if the user role meets the minimum requirements of the route
function hasRole(roleRequired) {
    if (!roleRequired) throw new Error('Required role needs to be set');

    return compose()
        .use(isAuthenticated())
        .use(function meetsRequirements(req, res, next) {
            if (req.user.role.indexOf(roleRequired) !== -1) {
                next();
            }
            else {
                res.send(403);
            }
        });
}
```

Here *auth.hasRole* is simple method/middleware, which is a curry design pattern. It checks use req and checks that user has valid permission to delete. In case of user don't have admin permission it return back with unautherize error message.
This is for admin and user relation. We also use another strategy at the end to validate user. Suppose we have expose our delete API and anyone can delete it. In that case we have to ensure that active user has to be the owner of the document. In that case first we get the owner id of the document and match it with requested user id. If matches than we delete the document.

```
BlogPostApiService.destroy(id, _.curry(hasPermission)(req.user))
//hasPermission implementation
function hasPermission(user, blogPost) {
    return user && (user.hasRole(UserEnums.roles.admin) || (user._id.toString() == blogPost.author.id.toString()));
}
```

Comment: This completely makes no sense. He asked about PHP backend, why you give node.js example?

Comment: coz it is not possible in client side. any one can hack that. I am suggesting what kind of implementation he can do. rather than giving code copy-paste thing. He has to write his own logic not copy paste the thing that is copied from anywhere

Comment: It is not copy/paste I gave. This is an idea. And question was

> How can I make sure that "normal" users or users that have not logged in cannot access the deletion operations of the API?

So I think he meant backend side not frontend side. But in fact question was how combination of both can solve this. Anyway Nodejs example for PHP guy is not relevant example anyway.

Comment: If a developer cant understand a simple functional language. I think he/she should leave coding :) anyways php is as senior as you are. You might right.